# Owin WebAPI passing Excetion to client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception, owin

When my WebAPI client calling the host from the same computer and there is an Exception thrown, the client is able to retrieve the error message through the response.

If my WebAPI Client calling the host within a local lan (but different computer). I only able to receive "internal server error" without the message.

May I know what is the best way to tell WebAPI NOT to filter the exception messages?

I have tried Owin IExceptionHandler but without success (I can only process / log the error). I can't figure out a way to forward the exception message to my client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer. In Owin Startup configuration, add "config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;"

Answer (score 1):

The client will be able retrieve the exception message if `customErrors` `mode` is set to `Off` in `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This technique can be used only in development environment, not in production or some other secure environment.

Click [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) and [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) for WebAPI exception handling details.